# Handling Python IOError

Tags: python

My program writes to a file using python. All goes well unless I already ran the file and kept the file open, throwing an IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'pathname'.

I'm wondering the best way to exit from the program and launch a message box to explain the issue to the user, instructing to close the previous file for overwrite.

```
def myFunction(self):
    with open(self.pathString, 'wb') as ofile:
    writer = csv.writer(ofile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, delimiter='\t')
    ...
    if IOError:
        QMessageBox.information(None, 'Information', 'A message')
        return
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the relevant code in question. As a quick answer, though, always use the `with` context manager when opening files - that way they'll always be closed when you exit the processing loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy:

```
try:
  result = do_here_what_can_cause_IOError
except IOError as e:
  log.error('Error when trying to perform do_here_what_can_cause_IOError: %s', e)
else:
  use_the_result_here
```

In a word, to catch any kind of exception Python throws, use try/except/else/finally

The documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html)